# Need to reset the Keyboard shortcuts defined

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I bound some keys by mistake, and they don't work any more, such as HOME, END, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT.

Is there a way to reset all the bound keys to their original state?

I know this might be duplicate but till yet none of the answers i saw helped.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can restore the key bindings or shortcuts as default but you can see the scheme in org.gnome.desktop.wm. You can open it with dcondf-editor (same path).